# Maven / Nexus : download artifact metadata in build directory

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

I would like to download the metadata for a specific  group/artifactId combination in my build directory. When fetching this info (see URL below), I want to use the maven/nexus credential as defined in the settings.xml

https://nexus.my.domain.com/repository/myRepo/com/group/artifact-id/maven-metadata.xml

I looked at the maven "dependency plugin", and searched around and did not find any way to do this.

Comment: Why the metadata? And not the real dependencies ?

Comment: Because each version of this artifact is a "backward compatibility test" and want to include all previous version of this artifact, and add them the the classpath before running the surefire plugin. This way if backward compatibility is broken, builds fail.  With the meta data, I can extract all versions and then loop and download artifiacts using maven dependency plugin

Comment: There are tools like https://revapi.org/ which could help here in a more convenient way..?

Comment: I must be missing something, can you not just download the file with curl?

Comment: because curl won't have the credentials & server list from settings.xml